# Counting only first appearance of item in R?

Tags: r

So I'm trying to find Greens in Regulation (on green in par minus 2 strokes) using shot data in R that looks like this:

```
Player     Shot Par To_Location   Hole
Tiger Woods 1   4   Fairway        1
Tiger Woods 2   4   Green          1 
Tiger Woods 3   4   Green          1
Tiger Woods 4   4   Hole           1
Tiger Woods 1   3   Rough          2
Tiger Woods 2   3   Green          2
Tiger Woods 3   3   Hole           2
Tiger Woods 1   4   Green          3
Tiger Woods 2   4   Green          3
Tiger Woods 3   4   Hole           3
```

I've been using the script below:

```
result <- df %>% 
group_by(Player) %>%
summarize(GIR = sum(To_Location == "Green" & Par - Shot > 1) / n())
```

But the values aren't correct, most likely because it double counts some of the greens (in the event that there's an eagle opportunity) but also possibly because I shouldn't be summing in this fashion?

I'd want a result that looked like this:

```
Player        GIR
Tiger Woods   .6666667
```

as he made green in regulation on two of the three holes.

Comment: Seems like your data is missing a grouping variable for "Hole". Looking at the data it's pretty clearly grouped, the first 4 rows together, the next 3, the 3 after that, but there's no column corresponding to that grouping. Presumably you want to count the first "Green" grouped by Player and this missing grouper. Once you have that, use the `dplyr::first()` function.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I have hole data, that should help!

Comment: Your variable name has a space in it, so you should wrap it in backticks, like `\`To Location\``... or, arguably better, not use variable names containing spaces. Along the same lines, you can't switch from `Shot` to `shot` or `Par` to `par_value` and expect the code to find the correct column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `top_n` from `dplyr` to get the first row.  Also, creates a hole variable as mentioned in the comments

```
g <- rle(df$Par)
df$hole <- rep(seq_along(g$values), times=g$lengths)

result <- df %>% 
  group_by(Player) %>%
  top_n(1, hole) %>%
  summarize(GIR = sum(`To Location` == "Green" & Par - Shot > 1) / n())
#        Player       GIR
# 1 Tiger Woods 0.6666667
```